# Pass TypeScript object to Window in Electron app

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

If I have a simple typescript class that just prints to the screen, like below, how can I access it on the front end in a simpler way?

**speak.ts**

```
export class Speak {
    public write() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
}
```

I know you are able to use

**index.html**

```
<script>
    var x = require('./speak');
    x.Speak.prototype.write(); // Prints "Hello"
</script>
```

The `require` statement has to assign to a variable for me to access this class. I'm not able to access it using `require('./speak');` on its own, trying to bring it into global scope.

Having to preface every command with "x.Speak.prototype" is a bit verbose, and could easily become much longer when multiple classes and interfaces are introduced.

I feel like I'm not doing this the right way. How can I bring data/functions over from TypeScript classes to operate on the front end?

**UPDATE**

When I try something like below in my `index.html` file

```
<script>
    var speak = new Speak();
    speak.write("some other stuff");
</script>
```

I get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Speak is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things involved.

1. ES6 -> CommonJS interop
2. class syntax

For the first point, you are declaring an ES6 module while consuming it in commonJs syntax.

that's why you need the extra `X` to hold on to the module object in CJS:

```
var X = require('./speak');
var speak = new X.Speak();

// or accessing the `Speak` class directly:
var Speak = require('./speak').Speak;
var speak = new Speak();
```

If you consume the same code in ES6, it would be:

```
import { Speak } from './speak'
 const s = new Speak();

// or
import * as X from './speak'
const s = new X.Speak();
```

Of course, ESM (ES6 Module system) is not available in every browser, so you need to transpile your TypeScript code down to ES5 and use some loader mechanism to load the module (like requireJS).

For the second point, you are writing a class. so you typically would create an instance of `Speak` and use it (following code assume you consume the code in a module, to avoid confusion with the first point):

```
var speak = new Speak();
speak.write();
```

If you don't need an instance, you can use a static method or just function:

```
export class Speak {
  static write() { ... }
}

// usage:
Speak.write();

// function
export function write() { ... }

// usage:
write();
```

Comment: To your first point, when I create an instance within script tags in my index.html file, as `var speak = new Speak();` I get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError, Speak is not defined`, same with the static class. To the second point, I understand but how can I consume in ES6 from the context of the HTML file?

Comment: The example about is using the `Speak` class directly inside the module. In script tag you will do `var x = require('./speak'); var speak = new x.Speak();` (if the `require()`) function is provided by some loader).

Comment: I didn't write it so to avoid confusion with the second point.

Comment: Thanks, doing `var x = require('./speak'); var speak = new x.Speak()` works. I also was able to do similar using `var x = require('./speak').Speak.prototype; x.write("some stuff");` Please add to your answer and I'll accept

Comment: I updated the answer by reversing the order. Hope that makes it more clear.